# Primefaces rowExpansion not working in primefaces 3.5

Tags: primefaces, datatable, row

I am trying to use the p:rowToggler and p:rowExpansion in my datatable. It was working fine on primefaces 3.2, recently i upgraded to primefaces 3.5. Since then it is not working. Following is the datatable with roToggler and rowExpansion

```
<p:datatable value="#{myBean.valueList}">
<p:column>
<p:rowToggler/>
</p:column>
<p:rowExpansion>
...
</p:rowExpansion>
</p:datatable>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Praveen

Comment: Clear your browser cache, tomcat temp files etc. Believe me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below,

```
<p:dataTable var="education" 
             value="#{backingBean.schoolList}" 
             reflow="true"
             paginator="true" 
             sortMode="multiple" 
             emptyMessage="No records found."
             rows="#{backingBean.rowsPerPage}">
                            
            <p:column headerText="Details" styleClass="Wid10">
                <p:rowToggler expandLabel="Show" collapseLabel="Hide" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
            </p:column>
            
            <p:column headerText="Center">
                <h:outputText value="#{education.centerName}"/>
            </p:column>
            
            <p:column headerText="Address">
                <h:outputText value="#{education.addr}" />
            </p:column>
                        
            <p:rowExpansion>
                <p:outputLabel value="Course: " styleClass="FontBold" />
                <BR />
                <h:outputText value="#{education.course}" />
                <Br />
                <p:outputLabel value="Details: " styleClass="FontBold" />
                <BR />
                    <h:outputText value="#{education.details}" />
            </p:rowExpansion>
        </p:dataTable>
```